# bulk delete from a many-to-many relation table based on a WHERE condition that checks ids in two lists

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

Assume that there is an employee table and a project table.
A relationship table emp_proj contains following column: `(id, emp_id, proj_id)`

I would like to delete rows from `emp_proj` that contain following pairs of `(emp_id, proj_id)` : `(1,101) , (1,102), (2,202), (3,303)`

Note that the table may contain other rows with emp_ids 1, 2 and 3.

How would I use `WHERE` clause that would compare these pairs ?

I thought of using nesting of `OR`s but that would complicate the query.

Also I would like to do a bulk delete operation that in one-go, would delete all rows that contain the concerned pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Postgres, your suggested approach might be the only option:

```sql
DELETE
FROM emp_proj
WHERE
    emp_id = 1 AND proj_id = 101 OR
    emp_id = 1 AND proj_id = 102 OR
    emp_id = 2 AND proj_id = 202 OR
    emp_id = 3 AND proj_id = 303;
```

Note that on certain other databases, such as MySQL, you could have used a tuple syntax which is a bit more terse:

```sql
DELETE
FROM emp_proj
WHERE
    (emp_id, proj_id) IN ((1, 101), (1, 102), (2, 202), (3, 303));
```

Comment: Thanks ! `OR` based syntax can be long-winded especially because I would like to construct this query dynamically when the function received the list of tuples that contain emp ids and project ids.

Comment: Constructing even a scalar `WHERE IN (...)` clause with a dynamic prepared statement can already be very challenging.  I'm not sure there is a perfect answer for your question.  But AFAIK the tuple syntax won't work on Postgres.

Comment: Actually the tuple syntax works fine in Postgresql 12. Ex: `select (1,2) in ((2,3),(3,4),(2,5),(1,2))` yields true.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm ... I wonder if the ANSI-92 standard mentions tuple syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not know. Read your comment, checked it and it worked.

Comment: This works only if the table has two columns. In my case, the table also has one or two more columns and I want to delete the rows where emp_id and proj_id are from the given pairs